# count items for each option in select

Tags: javascript, select, count

How can I count the number of div's with 'gallery-item' class I have for each option and append the number to the html for select corresponding option? something like London (2). Paris (1). Tokyo (3)

I have a simple example here

https://jsfiddle.net/2df58zqc/1/

```
let valueNew = () => {
      const SELECT_CONTENT = document.querySelectorAll('.select-content');
      const GALLERY_SELECT = document.querySelector('.gallery-select');
      SELECT_CONTENT.forEach((selectContent) => {
        selectContent.classList.remove('visible');
      });
      SELECT_CONTENT[GALLERY_SELECT.selectedIndex].classList.add('visible');
    };
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('gallery-select'), (select) =>
      select.addEventListener('change', valueNew, false),
    );

<div class="select-wrapper">
  <select class="gallery-select">
    <option>Lodon</option>
    <option>Paris</option>
    <option>Tokyo</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="select-content-list">
  <div class="select-content">
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="select-content">
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="select-content">
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to achieve this.

By creating an object that have the option text like city name in this example and display image information needed, use it to create both `<option />` and `<img />` elements dynamically. The image count for each option then can be available for each option text.

for example, this object may look like below `imageInfoByCity`

```js
const imageInfoByCity = {
  Tokoy: [
    {
      src: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
    }, {
      src: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
    }, {
      src: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
    }],
  Paris: [{
    src: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
  }],
  London: [{
    src: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
  }, {
    src: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
  }],
};
```

and before register the change event, use this information to create all `<option />` and `<img />`

```js
// use imageInfoByCity to create <option/> 
createSelectorOptions(imageInfoByCity)

// use imageInfoByCity to create <img />
createDisplayContent(imageInfoByCity)
```

for the createSelectorOptions implementation may look like below

```js
function createSelectorOptions(options){
  const gallerySelect = document.querySelector('.gallery-select');
   Object.entries(options).forEach( option => {
      const [city, imageInfo] = option;
      const optionDOM = document.createElement('option');
      optionDOM.innerHTML = `${city} (${imageInfo.length}) `
      gallerySelect.appendChild(optionDOM)
   })
}
```

here is the live example from [codepen](https://codepen.io/highjack/pen/xxwNaOR)

Comment: this is really nice, and many thanks, but unfortunately i cannot have an object or to create the items dynamically :(

Comment: if cannot create items dynamically, then may select all select-content elements, and loop through each `.select-content` class, find the count of children and append to each option by order. [example[(https://codepen.io/highjack/pen/gOaJVKQ)